# How to refresh NSManagedObject with the updated data - Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am currently stuck in the core data, There is a table view and detail view, the data is display on table view from core data NSManagedObject when i move to details view and update some data in database then, i move back to previous screen and retrieve data again from database but the core data revert me the previous values not the updated one, while the data is already updated in the database.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a sanity check, did you save the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your NSManagedObject (in the same Context) it's changing your model. Check if is the same object in both cases when you fetch or mantain it in memory

Comment: Why is it changing your model?

Comment: yes, i am using the same context in the both cases but still it revert me the old data. when i check the data base the updated value is still there.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that if you change your NSManagedObject property values this change is seen in a new fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` and implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol to update the table when the underlying data changes. The Xcode template (Master-Detail, check Core Data) provides such a sample implementation which you can just copy.